# Original Arabic text of Isaac Alfasi in last 3 responsum of Menahem Azariah da Fano

Tags: jewish-books, text, maseches-kesubos, responsa, arabic

In [Shut Harama Mipano](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1138&pgnum=309) (see opening page of book), the final three responsum are from the Rif, and explain three laws in tractate Kesubos. He wrote them in Arabic, and the Rama got a reputable translation from Venice. (A footnote indicates that these were translated by someone else, and are printed in [Rav Tam Yachya's](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14219-tam-jacob-b-david-ibn-yahya) Tumas Yesharim ([218-220](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42563&st=&pgnum=300&hilite=)).) Is the original Arabic text still extant?

Comment: Huh for some reason I always thought that book was "tamos yesharim" like bilam, but that of course makes no sense. Mishlei 11:3 is much more reasonable.

Comment: One of the translators is called Rabbi Shlomo Ma'aravi. I wonder if he may be identified with Rabbi Suleiman Ochana, one of the students of the Ari, who was sometimes called Rabbi Suleiman Ma'aravi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is. At least one manuscript has preserved it: MS Huntington 503, pp. [94r](https://digital.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/objects/5922b116-30cc-4510-ad00-58e4c5912894/surfaces/9eb448f0-c359-48c7-9fe3-c127df7efa2e/)-[117v](https://digital.bodleian.ox.ac.uk/objects/5922b116-30cc-4510-ad00-58e4c5912894/surfaces/69314fc2-a0f4-485a-a1c1-fc4311c5d7df/). See [Boaz Cohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boaz_Cohen)'s essay "[Three Arabic Halakic Discussions of Alfasi](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1451531?refreqid=excelsior%3A19b02f11a720e71565026e1256672ec7)" for a discussion of the responsa, the manuscript, the various translations, a reprint of the Judeo-Arabic of the manuscript and Cohen's own translation into Hebrew.

Comment: Oh great I'll look into that thanks