# Who was Rabbi Matzliach of the Upper Galilee?

Tags: rabbis, translation, rif-rabbi-isaac-alfasi

In [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128840/original-arabic-text-of-isaac-alfasi-in-last-3-responsum-of-menahem-azariah-da-f), it is brought that three halachic responsa by the Rif, originally written in Arabic, were translated for the Ramah of Fano into Hebrew. The Ramah [stated](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1138&pgnum=309) that the translation was done by two rabbis in Venice: Rabbi Matzliach of the Upper Galilee and Rabbi Shlomo Ma'aravi. I suspect that Rabbi Shlomo Ma'aravi is the Rasah, [Rabbi Suleiman Ochana](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%94), who was also sometimes known as Rabbi Suleiman Ma'aravi, and was one of the students ("cubs") of the Ari. But I don't know who Rabbi Matzliach was. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you looked in Seder hadroros not by the books now

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Didn't think about that. I'll check. Thanks!

Comment: So the Seder Hadoros HaKotzair (p.138) has a Rabbi Mazliach bar Eliyahu (aka אבן אל בצאק) who lived at the end of the 10 - early 11th century. From the chachmei Sicily and one of the main talmidim of Rav Hai Gaon and one of the main Rabbonim of the Aruch - does that sound right?

Comment: @Dov Sadly no. The two rabbis appear to have been contemporaries of the Ramah Mipano, and that is indeed the case for the Rasah. But thanks for the interesting info nonetheless.

Comment: Ah okay (15 char)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bibliographer/historian Abraham Yaari in his work  שלוחי ארץ ישראל (p. 273),  identifies מצליח מהגליל העליון alternatively as **רב מצליח מצפת**. He includes him in the chapter on emissaries from Ottoman occupied Israel in the 17th c. and states that he came to Venice. It does not appear to be the case that further biographical information is known about him beyond the fact that R. Menahem Azariah da Fano commissioned him to translate the aforementioned responsa.

Comment: Thank you! (15)

Comment: @Harel13 My pleasure